# Countable and Uncountable Sets in Metric Spaces

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I've been thinking about metric spaces recently, and a very abstract question came to mind. Please bear with me as I try to articulate it.

In a metric space, if there exists an uncountable set of vectors, can I choose a countable set of vectors in the space such that no element of my set is an element of the uncountable set?

As a follow up, I have questions about my question...

- Am I even allowed to ask this question
- Is this a question that can be answered in general? Are there certain conditions under which the answer would be "yes"?

Comment: Well, you can't choose *anything* from *any* set that isn't *in* the set.....

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with vectors or metric spaces; it is a matter of set theory.

Comment: But you can have have an uncountable set of things and a completely disjoint countable set of things.  You just don't *choose* the countable things from the uncountable things because they aren't *in* the countable set.... or you can select a countable set of things from an uncountable set and *then* *remove* them from the uncountable set.  The result of the things left behind will be an uncountable set.  .... So far as I can tell, vector are irrelevant.

Comment: "Am I even allowed to ask this question"  Well, you just *did*, didn't you?

Comment: I think better question would be ,based on what fleblood states, if choosing sets from an uncountable one makes sense in a metric space ? fleablood stated “no”

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little bit ambiguous depending on what you mean by '*choose*'.

So first I'll answer this: "*If there exists an uncountable set of vectors $A$, **is there a** non-empty countable set of vectors in the space such that no element of my set is an element of $A$?*"

Clearly, the answer is no. For let the set $A$ be all the vectors of the metric space $X$. Then there is no non-empty countable set of vectors of $X$ that is not included in $A$.

The other question, which I guess is the one you were trying to ask is: "*If there exists an uncountable set of vectors $A$, **and there is a** non-empty countable set of vectors in the space such that no element of my set is an element of $A$, **how could I define ('choose') such a set**?*"

The answer is as follows. Let $X$ be the set of all the vectors, since $A$ is not $X$, then $X-A$ is non-empty. Now pick a $x \in X-A$. The set $\{x\}$ alone is a countable set not included in $A$, but you probably meant a countably infinite set. If $X-A$ is finite, then obviously you can't define a countably infinite set not in $A$. If $X-A$ is infinite you can do a construct a set $B$ that is countably infinite as follows:

1. If $X-A$ is unbounded, then pick any $x_0 \in X-A$ and keep adding members from bigger and bigger balls around $x_0$ (e.g., balls of radius $1/n$). As long as you enforce the new members being different (if possible) from the ones that are already inside it will work.
2. If $X-A$ is bounded, then pick an accumulation point $x_0$ of $X-A$, and keep adding balls from smaller and smaller balls around $x_0$ (e.g., balls of radius $1/n$). The same logic as above applies.

You are done. This became bigger than I expected but I hope it's clear :)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much @Shiranai

Comment: @nicostr No problem. Don't forget to mark accepted answers by clicking the 'check' button  :)

Comment: This is a beautiful and elegant proof/answer. It can be used in a general fashion to prove many such things simply by tweaking it.